# Teradata - Combine distinct column values for multiple columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to combine values from multiple columns but without duplicate values. I could use UNION to select DISTINCT from each column and then use XMLAGG to group them into rows. But is there a better way? I'll probably have way more than 3 columns.

Table

```
Id    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
1     Red         Orange      Yellow
2     Blue        Green       Blue
```

Desired Output

```
Id    Columns
1     Red, Orange, Yellow
2     Blue, Green
```

Comment: Is it just three `ColumnN` type columns or do you have a whole mess of those? I'm thinking UNION & XMLAGG is probably the right way to go here since your schema isn't super awesome.

Comment: "I'll probably have way more than 3 columns."